# CMake: How to append extra compile definition to a dependent lib build

Tags: cmake

I have a shared library, `libShared`, which used to build different executables. What do I want to do is based on the build executable to add additional compile definition to the shared library.

`CMakeLists.txt` in my `lib` folder:

```
...
add_definition(-Dfoo -Dbar)
add_library(shared ${SOURCES})
```

`CMakeLists.txt` in `exe1` folder:

```
...
add_executable(exe1 ${SOUCE_FILES})
add_dependencies(exe1 shared)
# <How Do I append -DForExe1 compile definition to shared>?
target_link_libraries(exe1 shared)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` in `exe2` folder:

```
...
add_executable(exe2 ${SOURCES})
add_dependentcies(exe2 shared)
# <How Do I append -DForExe2 compile definition to shared>?
target_link_libraries(exe2 shared)
```

How do I do this in CMake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One **cannot** have *single* library target with *different* compile definitions.

Different compile definitions means different compilation actions, resulted in **different objects files**. But this would defeat the very concept of a library as something **already compiled** (and linked, in case of shared libraries).

---

If you have *small number* of possible compile definitions' set for a library, you may define library target for every set:

```
# Common definitions for any library.
add_definition(-Dfoo -Dbar)
# Common sources for any library
set(LIB_SOURCES ...)

# The library specialized for exe1.
add_library(lib_exe1 SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES})
# Library-specific definitions
target_compile_definitions(lib_exe1 PRIVATE -DForExe1)

# The library specialized for exe2.
add_library(lib_exe2 SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES})
# Library-specific definitions
target_compile_definitions(lib_exe2 PRIVATE -DForExe2)
```

Resulted libraries may be used when needed:

```
add_executable(exe1 ${SOUCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(exe1 lib_exe1)
```

---

If your library should be parametrized for some compile definition, consider to create a CMake function/macro, which creates a library instance when needed:

```
function(add_lib_for lib_name purpose_name)
    add_library(${lib_name} SHARED <sources>)
    target_compile_definitions(${lib_name} PRIVATE
        -Dfoo -Dbar # Common definitions
        -DFor${purpose_name} # Specific definition
    )
endfunction()
```

Usage:

```
add_executable(exe1 ${SOUCE_FILES})
add_lib_for(lib_exe1 Exe1)
target_link_libraries(exe1 lib_exe1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My two executables will never build together. They are just two different flavors. Since the shared lib is a dependency, I'm expecting the shared library will be built with different definition applied when building the executable. If it is not possible, it seems using CMake function is a good choice. Is it possible to change the purpose_name to a list of definitions? Thanks.

Comment: `Is it possible to change the purpose_name to a list of definitions?` - If you are about function's parameters, then yes, you may pass variable number of parameters to it (and process them). If you are about compile definitions, you may pass several `-D` options to `target_compile_definitions` command. Probably, `-D` option isn't needed.. I will investigate this later.